# Does Dask Dataframes not tolerate for NA Values in it? getting ValueError, cannot convert non-finite values

Tags: python, mysql, dask

I am still learning Dask to work with Databases:

I have a Dask dataframes that successfully copy from my local sql DB, which is like this:

```
ddf_authorized = dd.read_sql_table("cz_transaction_authorized", "mysql+pymysql://user_account:mysqlworld@127.0.0.1:3306/user","id")
ddf_mobileuser = dd.read_sql_table("cz_mobile_user", "mysql+pymysql://user_account:mysqlworld@127.0.0.1:3306/user","id")
ddf_users = dd.read_sql_table("users", "mysql+pymysql://user_account:mysqlworld@127.0.0.1:3306/user","id")
ddf_reader = dd.read_sql_table("reader", "mysql+pymysql://user_account:mysqlworld@127.0.0.1:3306/user","id")
ddf_mid = dd.read_sql_table("cz_mid","mysql+pymysql://user_account:mysqlworld@127.0.0.1:3306/user","id")
```

I am aware that my Local DB have lots of NA values in it, especially the transaction authorized DB which is 1.4 million rows, so then when I call `ddf_authorized.head()` just wanted to inspect my Dataframe, it gives me this error

`ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

I did try to use `fillna()` to fill the NA values but error still persist, like this:

```
for x in list(ddf_authorized.columns.values):
    if ddf_authorized[x].dtype != 'O':
        ddf_authorized[x] = ddf_authorized[x].fillna(0)
    else:
        ddf_authorized[x] = ddf_authorized[x].fillna("-")
```

Is there any safer way or things in mind, to inspect Dask Dataframes with these NA Values? since I am familiar with Pandas and didn't have any issues with NA values, and having to see this issue in Dask..

## Update: I am doing some research for the root cause..

I tried to export one of the table from my DB into csv files, and it is free from NA Values, here is the CSV file  http://www.sharecsv.com/s/147ba0bb507bb6dcc14a3a6c91af4eef/reader_table.csv

And then, I tried to read it with dask.read_csv

```
x = dd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data Science Journey/My Cashlez Work Assets/Insight 16 Desember/reader_table.csv")
```

if I run `x.head()` it run successfully without any error, but it didn't work if I read it directly from DB with y.head() as below:

```
y = dd.read_sql_table("reader", "mysql+pymysql://user_account:mysqlworld@127.0.0.1:3306/user","id")
y["id"] = ddf_reader["reader_id"].astype('int64')
y["devicetype_fk"] = ddf_reader["devicetype_fk"].astype('O')
y["serial_number"] = ddf_reader["serial_number"].astype('O')
```

so maybe this is an issue of `read_sql_table()`?

Answer (score 1):

Dask probably infers the wrong datatype: It assumes an integer column by looking at the top values. Then you run into the problem that the unexpected `NA` can't be converted to int. You don't get these problems with Pandas because in that case the whole column is considered to determine the data type.

Try to use the [`meta` keyword of read_sql_table](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table) to explicitly specify the columns' dtypes (e.g. float (for numeric types with nans and infs) or object (for arbitrarily mixed types)).

You can pass an empty pandas df as meta, e.g.

```
meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2']).astype({'col1': float})
```

where you explicitly define the required dtypes `{'col1': float}`. Default is object. This appears to require the specification of the `npartitions` (as keyword argument to `read_sql_table`), which you might want to do anyway, to tune dask performance.

Comment: by adding meta, is it the same as convert 1-on-1 columns with astype() method? or how to specify meta on it?